# quorum "gas price not 0" and "intrincis gas too low"

Tags: gas, nodejs, quorum, price

iam running quorum blockchain this my code
[image]

if I put   gasPrice as 0 the error it is showing  "intrinsic gas too low"
[image]
if I put gas Price  higher the error it is showing "gas price not 0"
[image]
my genesis file

[image]
my command line

PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore nohup  geth --datadir ./ --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 822 --raft --raftport 50510 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8510 -rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --rpccorsdomain http://remix.ethereum.org --emitcheckpoints --port 25510 --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8559 --wsapi=db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin,personal,web3 --wsorigins=* --nat=none --allow-insecure-unlock    >/dev/null &

how to solve his error

Answer (score 0):

The reason your transaction is failing is that you have a typo in your `txObject`. You have specified `gasLimt` instead of `gasLimit`.

Also, just to clarify - you are confusing Gas Price with Gas Limit.
Gas Limit is the amount of gas you are willing to spend on the transaction. If the transaction fails due to "gas too low" then you need to increase the amount you pass in the transaction.

Gas Price is the ​cost that must be paid for the amount of gas used. This is not currently supported by Quorum and must be set to zero.